# Issue with Sub URLS in Domain Name settings

Tags: dns, kong

I have hosted an Kong Gateway application in one of our server which gives us an output url with a public IP  111.92.xx.xx

http://111.92.xx.xx:8000

And i have different sub urls like

http://111.92.xx.xx:8000/ABC

http://111.92.xx.xx:8000/ABC?find={bla,bla,bla}

http://111.92.xx.xx:8000/XYZ/findOne?access_token=ksdgasdgausygdasj     etc

This working fine and accessible everywhere.

Now i want to add a domain name for my ip "111.92.xx.xx:8000"

then may be my urls will be

http://exmaple.com and

http://exmaple.com/ABC

http://exmaple.com/ABC?find={bla,bla,bla}

http://exmaple.com/XYZ/findOne?access_token=ksdgasdgausygdasj

I have checked with my network admin and added the DNS settings for this but now i can only able to access the main url like this "http://exmaple.com:8000"

And I can't able to to access the sub URLs, If i need to access the Sub URLs i need to pass the Host header like "Host: 111.92.xx.xx".

We have tried different options in DNS settings like URL Redirect, Adding A or CNAME record... but still it is not working

So how to resolve this issue? Is it some thing that we can do in DNS settings or in myserver i have to make some changes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have mapped your domain name to host only.
11.92.xx.xx to example.com

Rather map host:port to domain name
11.92.xx.xx:8000 to example.com